# What does it mean to "translate" a graphics object?

Tags: graphics, terminology, translation

Not a long question. Can anyone explain what the word "translation" means in the context of graphics? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Translation is just moving something (up, down, or sideways).

Answer (score 2):

Move an object - don't rotate or scale or distort it, just move it

Answer (score 2):

Translation, as said, is moving an object.  This is one of the affine transformations (which means it doesn't distort the object).  There are a few others, the 2D versions of which are described [here](http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/GeneralGraphics/Transforms/transforms2d.htm).  (Note that shearing, the final one listed, isn't affine).

Answer (score 1):

It literally means to translate coordinates from one graph system to another using a mathmatical function.

In normal 2d/3d geometry this is accomplished by adding or subtracting values to move the origin of one system to the orgin of the other.

Ie - move the object from one spot to another.

(Ps this is somewhat simplified.)